Docker Container for .NET 8 Web API Fails When Deployed to Azure Container Registry (ACR)
I'm working on a .NET 8 web api and using Docker to containerize it. The app works on my local machine, but fails when deployed to ACR. Before that I was running the app on .NET 7, and there were no issues with deploying it to ACR.
Dockerfile:
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["MyProject.API/MyProject.API.csproj", "MyProject.API/"]
COPY ["MyProject.Core/MyProject.Core.csproj", "MyProject.Core/"]
COPY ["MyProject.Models/MyProject.Models.csproj", "MyProject.Models/"]
RUN dotnet restore "MyProject.API/MyProject.API.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/MyProject.API"
RUN dotnet build "MyProject.API.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "MyProject.API.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyProject.API.dll"]

Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance!
UPD: The web app that uses this container image shows "Connected! 504.0 GatewayTimeout" in logs

What does "fails when deployed to ACR" mean? Please include the actual steps you're trying to perform, what error message you're getting etc. Remember, we're not at your computer, so it's up to you to be pro-active and include the basic information so that we have the full picture of what's happening.

Provide you github repo if possible ?

Provide the screenshot of error message you're encountering.

@SirraSneha the error message is 504.0 GatewayTimeout. The web app log stream shows "Connected! 504.0 GatewayTimeout"

@Nataly Verner, it would be easier to solve if you provide the code you've tried.

I created a sample ASP .NET 8 Web API and successfully deployed it to azure app service via Azure Container Registry.
The error message you're encountering might be related to Environment configuration issues.
I successfully pushed the image to container registry.

Right click on your project in solution explorer=>publish=>Azure => Azure container registry =>select your registry => Finish.






While creating azure web app make sure you choose publish option as Container.

Configure the App Service to use the correct container image from your Azure Container Registry (ACR).


After creating the azure app service.

Open settings => Configuration => startup command

Add dotnet containertestapp18.dll  as Startup command.



While creating the app itself, the environment variables are automatically configured. However, ensure that the following environment variables are set in your app.

Local output :

Output after deployment:


@Nataly Verner Is your issue resolved?

Updating my .NET from 8.0.400 to 8.0.401 fixed my issue of pushing the image to ACR when deploying on Azure container Apps (ACA)
